# How to use QT Brush Stroke font for a single word in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I would like to use the QT Brush Stroke font for a special word in my LaTeX document.
How can I do this? Is there a special package that I need to install / import?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}

  \defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
  \newfontfamily\qtbrush{QT Brush Stroke}
\else
  \newcommand\qtbrush{\usefont{T1}{pbsi}{xl}{n}}
\fi

\pagestyle{empty} % To format the MWE for TeX.SX

\begin{document}
One {\qtbrush word}.
\end{document}
```

[image: QT Brush sample]

If you want to get fancy, you could `\DeclareTextFontCommand\textqt{\qtbrush}` and be able to write `\textqt{This is in QT Brush Stroke.}`

If you don’t have the font installed, the OTF version is in the `qualitype` package and the 8-bit version is in the `brushscr` package.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. When I tried your LaTeX code, an error displays, saying: "package fontspec error: QT Brush Stroke font is not found". How can I resolve this? Thank you,

Comment: @jschnieder Install the fonts. On CTAN, the `.otf` version is in the `qualitype` package and the Type 1 version is in the `brushscr` package.